# Alpine ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: py3-pandas (missing):

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I have the following `dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ADD crontab.txt /crontab.txt
ADD  script.sh /script.sh
COPY entry.sh /entry.sh

ADD app /app 

RUN chmod 755 /script.sh /entry.sh
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt

# install dependencies
# the lapack package is only in the community repository
RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
&& apk update \
&& apk add --no-cache python3 py-pip py3-setuptools python-dev py3-lxml py3-requests  py3-numpy py3-cssselect py3-pandas

RUN apk --update add --no-cache \ 
lapack-dev \ 
gcc \
freetype-dev

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
gfortran \
musl-dev \
g++
RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h

#RUN pip3 install cython
RUN pip3 install pymongo xlrd

CMD ["/entry.sh"]
```

when I try to build the dockerfile, I received the error saying that `py3-pandas (missing)`.

I am wondering whether that's the Alpine package management issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue by doing just:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache py3-pandas
```

Some comments here:

- If you are going to use the edge/testing packages repository already, then you would be better using the `alpine:edge` image, although I would not advise this for a production server, of  course
- Using another package repository than the default one on `apk` can be done on a one run basis using the option

  ```
  -X, --repository REPO   Use packages from REPO
  ```

  <sup>*From `apk --help`*</sup>
- The package `python-dev` does not exist in the edge/testing repository, you should use `python3-dev`

---

**Important disclaimer**: this solution does involve using the testing repository and the edge rolling release branch of Alpine, [and is thus not recommended for production use](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Aports_what_is_edge).

---

So, in the end, all your dependencies can be installed doing:

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
        py-pip \
        py3-setuptools \
        python3-dev \
        py3-lxml \
        py3-requests  \
        py3-numpy \
        py3-cssselect \
        py3-pandas \
        lapack-dev \ 
        gcc \
        freetype-dev
```

*Note that I didn't add the build dependancies there, as they don't seems to be related to your issue at hand*

Comment: i have an issue with using numpy from apk like this. i get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` at runtime

Comment: @ldgorman seems like you have some clues in the comments of [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386153/how-to-reference-an-apk-packages-inplace-of-a-pip-package), this have to do with your usage of virtual environments.

Comment: yea, the problem is getting apk packages into my virtual env... building my application as a package so cant really drop the venv

Answer (score -1):

Don't use alpine images for python; there's too many issues. Use a something like python:slim-buster. You can then just install your requirements with:

```
FROM python:3.8.4-slim-buster
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
```