# how to reference an apk packages inplace of a pip package

Tags: docker, pip, alpine-linux

I have a python project that gets containerized with docker using an alpine base image. I have used `numpy` in the project so I now need to add that dependency. The `alpine` package manager `apk` provides the package `py3-numpy`.

In my dockerfile I have added `RUN apk add py3-numpy` so the dependency is there but when I run the containerized application i get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`.

So the question is, how do i replace `numpy` with `py3-numpy`?

Comment: The same py3 version? Virtual environment?

Comment: using tox virtual environment and yes python 3.8

Comment: Virtual environments don't have access to packages installed globally by system package managers. Packages in virtual environments must be installed with `pip` or `conda`.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  You often don't need a virtual environment in a Docker container since the container itself is isolation from other Python installations.

Comment: @DavidMaze ill give it a go